# check if a string from a file exists in a list of list of strings: python

Tags: python

I am reading a `.csv` file and saving it to a matrix called `csvfile`, and the matrix contents look like this (abbreviated, there are dozens of records):

> [['411-440854-0', '411-440824-0', '411-441232-0', '394-529791', '394-529729', '394-530626'], <...>, ['394-1022430-0', '394-1022431-0', '394-1022432-0', '***another CN with a switch in between'], ['394-833938-0', '394-833939-0', '394-833940-0'], <...>, ['394-1021830-0', '394-1021831-0', '394-1021832-0', '***Sectionalizer end connections'], ['394-1022736-0', '394-1022737-0', '394-1022738-0'], <...>, ['394-1986420-0', '394-1986419-0', '394-1986416-0', '***weird BN line check'], ['394-1986411-0', '394-1986415-0', '394-1986413-0'], <...>, ['394-529865-0', '394-529686-0', '394-530875-0', '***Sectionalizer end connections'], ['394-830900-0', '394-830904-0', '394-830902-0'], ['394-2350772-0', '394-2350776-0', '394-2350774-0', '***Sectionalizer present but no end break'], <...>]

and I am reading a text file into a variable called `textfile` and the content looks like this:

```
...
object underground_line {
    name SPU123-394-1021830-0-sectionalizer;
    phases AN;
    from SPU123-391-670003;
    to SPU123-395-899674_sectionalizernode;
    length 26.536;
    configuration SPU123-1/0CN15-AN;
}

object underground_line {
    name SPU123-394-1021831-0-sectionalizer;
    phases BN;
    from SPU123-391-670002;
    to SPU123-395-899675_sectionalizernode;
    length 17.902;
    configuration SPU123-1/0CN15-BN;
}

object underground_line {
    name SPU123-394-1028883-0-sectionalizer;
    phases CN;
    from SPU123-391-542651;
    to SPU123-395-907325_sectionalizernode;
    length 771.777;
    configuration SPU123-1CN15-CN;
}
...
```

I want to see if a portion of `name` line in `textfile` (anything after `SPU123-` and before `-0-sectionalizer`) exists in `csvfile` matrix. If it does not exist, I want to do something (increment a counter) and I tried several ways including below:

```
counter = 0
for noline in textfile:
    if 'name SPU123-' in noline:
        if '-' in noline[23]:
            if ((noline[13:23] not in s[0]) and  (noline[13:23] not in s[1]) and (noline[13:23] not in s[2]) for s in csvfile):
                counter = counter+1
        else:
            if ((noline[13:24] not in s[0]) and  (noline[13:24] not in s[1]) and (noline[13:-24] not in s[2]) for s in csvfile):
                counter = counter+1
print counter
```

This is not working. I also tried with `if any((noline......)` in the above code sample and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Are there more ```name```s in ```textfile``` than items in the matrix?  is the matrix just a list of lists?

Comment: @wwii I just edited the question with `print csvfile` output. The `textfile` has a lot more objects than I showed in the question. That is just a small snippet of the entire file. I am trying to check the existence of each `name` (between certain indices as I explained in the question) in `csvfile` matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for a string `s` in a list of lists `l`:

```
>>> l = [['str', 'foo'], ['bar', 'so']]

>>> s = 'foo'
>>> any(s in x for x in l)
True

>>> s = 'nope'
>>> any(s in x for x in l)
False
```

Implementing this into your code (assuming that `noline[13:23]` is the string your are wanting search for, and then increment `counter` if it is not in `csvfile`):

```
counter = 0
for noline in textfile:
    if 'name SPU123-' in noline:
        if '-' in noline[23]: noline[13:23]:
            if not any(noline[13:23] in x for x in csvfile) and not any(noline[13:23] + '-0' in x for x in csvfile):
                counter += 1
        else:
            if not any(noline[13:24] in x for x in csvfile) and not any(noline[13:24] + '-0' in x for x in csvfile):
                counter  += 1
```

Comment: it is not working. For example I tried `any ('394-1260252' in x for x in csvfile)` and it generated `False` instead of `True`

Comment: `csvfile` may not be structured how it appears above... can you `print csvfile` and show us the results.

Comment: The problem is that in `csvfile` that string has `-0` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Since your matrix includes loads upon loads of values, it's very slow to iterate over it all each time.

Assemble your values into a mapping instead (a `set` in this case since there are no associated data) since hash table lookups are very fast:

```
s = {v for r in matrix for v in r if re.match(r'\d[-\d]+]\d$',v)} #or any filter more appropriate for your notion of valid identifiers

if noline[13:23] in s: #parsing the identifiers instead would be more fault-tolerant
   #do something
```

Due to the preliminary step, this will only start outperforming the brute-force approach beyond a certain scale.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re, itertools
```

Flatten `csvfile` -- `data` is an iterator

```
data = itertools.chain.from_iterable(csvfile)
```

Extract relevant items from data and make it a set for performance (avoid iterating over data multiple times)

```
data_rex = re.compile(r'\d{3}-\d+')
data = {match.group() for match in itertools.imap(data_rex.match, data) if match}
```

Quantify the the names that are not in data.

```
def predicate(match, data = data):
    '''Return True if match not found in data'''
    return match.group(1) not in data

# after SPU123- and before -0-
name = re.compile(r'name SPU123-(\d{3}-\d+)-')
names = name.finditer(textfile)
# quantify
print sum(itertools.imap(predicate, names))
```